# How do I open my React app again after restarting my computer on local host?

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, localhost

I started a react project but now I don't know how to open it again in the localhost 3000 server. Do I just open the file again or do a npm command?

Comment: from the root of your project directory, try `npm start` . I guess thats how you started your dev server in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You should run your project through terminal with the `npm start` command again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just figured it out myself lol I just opened the terminal at my folder and did an 'npm start' command. Sorry newbie here

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have in the package.json file under the script function start if is then in terminal write `npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and write > `cd (your project name)` and then press enter, then press `npm start` and press enter.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where your react files are located then right click choose open in terminal (in my case I was using windows 11).Then run "npm start"

Answer (score -1):

type `npm run dev` in terminal and then hit enter you will get localhost URL.